# What is the probability of drawing five cards of the same suit from a deck of 52 cards?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

[image: This is an image of the WebAssign problem in case I missed something obvious]To answer this question, I tried using the combinations formula in the following manner:
I first obtained the number of elements in the sample space ( the number of 5 card hands that could be drawn from a deck of 52 cards) by calculating *C*(52,5)=2,598,000 and then calculated the number of 5 card hands that had cards all from the same suit by calculating *C*=(4,1) and *C*=(13,5) and multiplying those values together to obtain a total of 5148 different hands containing five cards of the same suit. I then divided this value by 2,598,000 to obtain the probability of a 5 card hand being drawn from a deck of 52 cards having all of its cards be of the same suit. This gave me a value of ~0.001981524 (which is the probability rounded to seven decimal places).

Comment: You made a mistake in the denominator $C(52,5)=2,598,960$

Answer (score 0):

You choose the first card.  The chance the second card is of the same suit is $p = \frac{12}{51}$.  The probability the third card is the same suit (given the second was as well) is $\frac{11}{50}$.  Can you continue?